# Retrieving RSS Feed URL from Mail.app?

Tags: url, apple-mail, rss

I have added an RSS feed to Apple's Mail.app. How can I retrieve the URL for the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Terminal application under /Applications/Utilities, run:

`for i in ~/Library/Mail/RSS/*/Info.plist; do defaults read "${i%.plist}" RSSFeedURLString; done`

Sourced from http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080319094830396